# QR decomposition and Gram Schmidt process

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition

Let $A\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$, invertible matrix. I need to decompose $A=QR$ where $Q$ is an orthogonal matrix and $R$ is an upper triangular.

Now, if $A=[a_1,\ldots a_n]$ and we apply Gram Schmidt process on it's columns, we get:

$u_1 = a_1 \\ u_2 = a_2 - \frac{\langle u_1,a_2 \rangle }{\|u_1\|^2}u_1 \\ u_k = a_k - \sum_{j=1}^{k-1} \frac{\langle u_j, a_k \rangle }{\|u_j\|^2}u_j$

Rearranging the terms:

$a_1 = u_1 \\ a_2 = u_2 + \frac{\langle u_1,a_2 \rangle }{\|u_1\|^2}u_1 \\ a_k = u_k + \sum_{j=1}^{k-1} \frac{\langle u_j, a_k \rangle }{\|u_j\|^2}u_j$

Now, before moving into a matrix multipication form, I need to do something with the $\{u_1,\ldots, u_n\}$, representing them in a similar form to the other terms.

How?

Comment: How is it not in similar form?

Comment: You are subtracting scalars from vectors

Comment: I've fixed the repeating typo.

Comment: are you making sure that all your $u's$ are of length one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand. The $u_i$ form the columns of the matrix $Q$. The coefficient on $u_j$ in the equation for $a_i$ is $r_{ij}$.

Comment: What would be $r_{11}$?

Comment: $r_{11}$ is the coefficient on $u_1$ in the equation for $a_1$, which is $1$. (Actually, you usually want $Q$ to have orthonormal columns, in which case $u_1=a_1/\| a_1 \|$ and $r_{11}=\| a_1 \|$.)

Comment: I was trying to follow a Wikipedia article about this subject:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition#Using_the_Gram.E2.80.93Schmidt_process

They seemed to use an identity made the matrix "more neat". Could you have a look please?

Comment: In the Wikipedia article, $r_{11} = \langle e_1, a_1 \rangle$ somehow.

Comment: $r_{11} = \frac{\langle e_1,a_1 \rangle}{\| e_1 \|^2} = \frac{\langle e_1,a_1 \rangle}{1} = \langle e_1,a_1 \rangle$. This is because $e_1=u_1/\| u_1 \|$, so $e_1$ is unit. It isn't any neater than what you've written, it just hides the normalization in the definition of the $e_k$.

Comment: So are you implying that $\langle e_1, a_1 \rangle = 1$?

Comment: No, $\langle e_1,a_1 \rangle$ could be anything between $-\| a_1 \|$ and $\| a_1 \|$. $\| e_1 \|^2=1$, though.

Comment: @AlonAlon Sorry, I made some seemingly contradictory remarks. They don't actually contradict each other, but they involve different conventions. If you take $Q$, as usual, to have orthonormal columns, then $r_{11}=\langle e_1,a_1 \rangle=\frac{\langle u_1,a_1 \rangle}{\| u_1 \|^2}$. If you don't normalize the columns of $Q$, you can take $r_{11}=1$.

Comment: Could you explain why $u_1 = \langle e_1, a_1 \rangle e_1$?

Comment: @AlonAlon I made another typo between negotiating my way through the two conventions. Non-orthonormal columns: $u_1=a_1$, $r_{11}=1$. Orthonormal columns: $e_1=a_1/\| a_1 \|$, $r_{11}=\langle e_1,a_1 \rangle$. Then $a_1 = r_{11} e_1$ because $\langle e_1,a_1 \rangle e_1 = \langle \frac{a_1}{\| a_1 \|},a_1 \rangle \frac{a_1}{\| a_1 \|} = a_1 \frac{\| a_1 \|^2}{\| a_1 \|^2} = a_1$.

Comment: I am still a little confused. Lets take $[u_1, \ldots, u_n]$ (not normalized). Can you show why the matrix multiplication gives $r_{11}=1$? Thanks

Comment: You can view matrix multiplication like this: $C=AB$ if $c_i = \sum_{j=1}^n a_j b_{ji}$ for $i=1,\dots,n$. In other words, $c_i$ is the linear combination of the columns of $a$ given by the coefficients in the $i$th column of $B$. So when $u_1=a_1$, you want $r_{11}=1$ and $r_{j1}=0$ for $j=2,\dots,n$. Going over a column, we have $a_2=u_2+...$, so $r_{22}=1$ and $r_{21}$ is the "...". And so forth; with non-normalized columns we end up with $1$s on the diagonal of $R$.